# Node SQLite3 - crashes when running insert on specific table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I have a SQLite database I am trying to add data to with the sqlite3 package. My query is as follows, and works in the SQLite command line.

```
'INSERT INTO `EVENTS`(`ID`,`EventName`,`EventSociety`,`BookerName`,`BookerEmail`,`BookerStudentID`,`BookerPhone`,`TimeStart`,`TimeEnd`,`EquipmentList`,`EventSearchYear`,`EventSearchMonth`,`EventSearchDay`) VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);';
```

And I'm using this code to insert to the database in node.

```
    db.run("begin transaction");
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO `EVENTS`(`ID`,`EventName`,`EventSociety`,`BookerName`,`BookerEmail`,`BookerStudentID`,`BookerPhone`,`TimeStart`,`TimeEnd`,`EquipmentList`,`EventSearchYear`,`EventSearchMonth`,`EventSearchDay`) VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);';
    console.log(sql);
    db.run(sql,(err) => {
        res.send('ok');
    });
    db.run("commit");
```

Trying this in node hard crashes, with a `Illegal instruction: 4`. However, it is only happening on two tables, both with over 5 fields, in my database, and not any other smaller ones. Is there a character limit I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid crash, we need to handle error as below:

Example

The line `db.run(sql, params, function (err) {` in below example:

```
  let sql = `INSERT INTO Users(id,firstName,lastName,email,password,permissionLevel) VALUES (?,?,?, ?,?,?)`;
  let params = [uuid4(), "fn1", "ln1", "a@a2.com", "pwd1", 0];
  db.run(sql, params, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error: Insert failed: ", err.message);
      console.error("Error: Full error: ", err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("insert success");
  });
```